# Not able to edit Public Server Name for embedded Tomcat

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

we are using Artifactory 6.20.0 in docker-compose mode. Stack is up and running fine. But I am not able to edit the "Public Server Name" in HTTP settings. It is greyed out.

How can I change it?

From Which file TomCat picks these values?

As per my understanding If I change Http settings and use nginx or tomcat. Still my Artifactory is reachable using same address which embedded Tomcat has provided and nginx will be only used for the path based routing. or nginx takes care of both parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note '[HTTP settings](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy)' in Artifactory UI is a template to generate the reverse proxy configuration according to provided fields and you can use the same snippet downloaded and install directly in the corresponding directory of your reverse proxy server.

Answers to your queries:

1. Embedded tomcat will not pickup any values from this template, it runs on 8081 (over http) by default.
2. As stated above, changing Http settings in UI will not help as it is a simple template. You must have a reverse proxy installed and place the required configuration on reverse proxy directories in order to access Artifactory over a DNS(http/https). Please refer to [Configuring Reverse Proxy](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF6X/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy) wiki page for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am astonished to see in my current setup There are artifactory instances. When I login to their http settings I see their public name is changed and it runs on port 80. but I am  unable to understand how to do it

Comment: it runs on 80 with any reverse proxy like Nginx or Apache?